# caching last k results of a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, caching, memoization

I want to write a function that accepts a single-argument function f, and an integer k, and returns a function that behaves the same as f except it caches the last k results of f.

For instance, if memoize is the function we're after, and let mem_f = memoize(f, 2), then:

```
    mem_f(arg1) -> f(arg1) is computed and cached  
    mem_f(arg1) -> f(arg1) is returned from cache  
    mem_f(arg2) -> f(arg2) is computed and cached  
    mem_f(arg3) -> f(arg3) is computed and cached, and f(arg1) is evicted
```

What I have done is:

```
def memoize(f,k):
    cache = dict()

    def mem_f(*args):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        result = f(*args)
        cache[args]= result
        return result 
    return mem_f
```

This function returns the result from cache and if it is not in cache, it is computed and cached. However, I am not clear **how to cache only last k results of f?** I am newbie, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This would need an additional data structure to keep the keys(=parameters) called at last. One such structure could be a `collections.deque`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to do the caching. I accepts a `maxsize` parameter to control how much it caches:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=2)
def test(n):
    print("calling function")
    return n * 2

print(test(2))
print(test(2))
print(test(3))
print(test(3))
print(test(4))
print(test(4))
print(test(2))
```

results:

> calling function
>   4
>   4
>   calling function
>   6
>   6
>   calling function
>   8
>   8
>   calling function
>   4

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You can fix the code you have by using `OrderedDict` like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def memoize(f, k):
    cache = OrderedDict()

    def mem_f(*args):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        result = f(*args)
        if len(cache) >= k:
            cache.popitem(last=False)
        cache[args]= result
        return result 
    return mem_f,cache
```

## Testing it out

```
def mysum(a, b):
    return a + b

mysum_cached,cache = memoize(mysum, 10)
for i in range(100)
    mysum_cached(i, i)

print(cache)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([((90, 90), 180), ((91, 91), 182), ((92, 92), 184), ((93, 93), 186), ((94, 94), 188), ((95, 95), 190), ((96, 96), 192), ((97, 97), 194), ((98, 98), 196), ((99, 99), 198)])
```

This version of `memoize` will likely work well for your own code. However, for production code (ie code that other people have to rely on), you should probably use the standard library function (`functools.lru_cache`) that Mark Meyer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the excellent suggestion of Mark Meyer, here's what the solution looks like using `lru_cache` and the terminology of your question:

```
from functools import lru_cache


def memoize(f, k):
    mem_f = lru_cache(maxsize=k)(f)
    return mem_f


def multiply(a, b):
    print("Called with {}, {}".format(a, b))
    return a * b


def main():
    memo_multiply = memoize(multiply, 2)
    print("Answer: {}".format(memo_multiply(3, 4)))
    print("Answer: {}".format(memo_multiply(3, 4)))
    print("Answer: {}".format(memo_multiply(3, 7)))
    print("Answer: {}".format(memo_multiply(3, 8)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

```
Called with 3, 4
Answer: 12
Answer: 12
Called with 3, 7
Answer: 21
Called with 3, 8
Answer: 24
```